# Set selected item on the layout

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a css class to indicate if an element is selected (.active)

in Main.js

```
<Layout>
    <Route path="/cars/:id" exact strict component={ Car } />
    <Route path="/something-else" component={ OtherComponent } />
</Layout
```

in my Layout.js

I just have a list of links

```
<Link to="/cars/1">car 1</Link>
<Link to="/cars/2">car 2</Link>
<Link to="/cars/3">car 3</Link>
```

as you can see I want to use the same layout in both components **Car** an **OtherComponent**

this only works in the Car component. but I want something like this in the Layout component so I can compare the id with the car id and mark the item as active.

```
useEffect(() => {

    const id = props.match.params.id;

}, [props])
```

is there a way to do this without useContext ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `<NavLink>`
A special version of the `<Link>` that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

`<NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>`

activeClassName: string

The class to give the element when it is active. The default given class is active. This will be joined with the className prop.

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="active">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use withRouter hoc to get match as prop in your Layout component.

```
function Layout(props) {
  console.log(props.match.params.id); 
}

export default withRouter(Layout);
```

Comment: looking a little bit better but params is empty

Comment: does your current route has any params?